# HTML Extension not available in _LogOnPartial.cshtml (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I 've done the foloowing:

created the following a class/method:

```
namespace MyApp.Extensions
{
    public static class Html
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, string action, object routeValues, string imagePath, string alt)
        { ...}
     }
}
```

Put namespace MyApp.Extensions in ~Views/Web.config. To see if it shows up in Itellisense i tried to type in _Layout.cshtml and it worked without any problem.

BUT: it doesn't show up in _LogOnPartial.cshtml.

Why? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. It could be a bug in the Intellisense. Closing and reopening the Razor view usually solves the issue. Try running your project and you will see that your helper works.

Comment: Darin you 're right: closing and reopening solved this tricky situation! Why is this happening? is this "normal" behavior? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SavvasSopiadis, no, it is not a normal behavior. It's a bug.